# Java/Eclipse: "Lambda expressions cannot be used in an evaluation expression"

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda

I wrote the following lambda expression

```
int size = ((List<?>) receipt.getPositions().stream().filter(item -> true).collect(Collectors.toList())).size()
```

The variable `size` is computed correctly!

But when I try to inspect it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) or try to see the result of the expression in Eclipse expressions view, I get the following error:

"Lambda expressions cannot be used in an evaluation expression"

[image]

Are there any other opportunities to see the result of such an expression instead of storing it to a variable?

P.S.: I am using Java 8 and Eclipse neon.2

Comment: If you use an internet search engine, the error message "Lambda expressions cannot be used in an evaluation expression" will find some information about that. Basic answer is no, but maybe in the future yes.

Comment: Also: why not just use count() instead of collect(...).size() ?

Comment: Just use `receipt.getPositions().size()`. This can be evaluted by the debugger without problems.

Comment: Just for reference and later use: Seems to be this bug in jdt: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=448473

Comment: you need to upgrade you version of eclipse to IntelliJ :p

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution for this, that works is to convert your lambda in an anonymous class creation. Creating a variable of the interface needed, you'll get a debuggable expression.

```
    Predicate<Object> predicate = new Predicate<Object>() {
        @Override
        public boolean test(Object item) {
            return true;
        }
    };
    int size = ((List<?>) receipt.getPositions().stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList())).size();
```

Now, if you're standing at the line "int size = ..." while debugging, you can view the result of following:

```
((List<?>) receipt.getPositions().stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList())).size()
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: This works for the original question but doesn't help you if you tried to write a lambda inside a detail formatter or the debug view. You can't create your own predicate because you'll get  "Anonymous type declaration cannot be used in an evaluation expression/Constructor of a local type cannot be used in an evaluation expression". You just have to use regular Java logic, I'm afraid.